# How to fix list out of index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Can someone help me with rearranging my code so that my list index is no longer out of range?

Update: The formula I'm trying to apply is in the image below and what is supposed to be inside of the for loops

[Formula I'm Trying to Replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAh5h.png)

def total_balance(entries):

```
##lists for storage
wealth_retirement = list() 
wealth = list()   
temp = list()  

##get values from GUI
r = float(entries[F_MEAN_RETURN].get())/100
noise = (float(entries[F_STD_DEV].get())/100) * np.random.randn(70)

w_y = float(entries[F_ANN_CONTRIB].get())
y = int(entries[F_YEARS_CONTRIB].get())
y_r = int(entries[F_YEARS_RETIRE].get())

spent = float(entries[F_ANN_SPEND].get())

## 10 runs 
for i in range(10):

    for years in range(70):

        if years < y:
            wealth[years + 1] = (wealth[years]*(1+r+noise[years])) + w_y   
        elif years >= y and years < 70:
            if years == y:
                wealth_retirement[i] = wealth[years]
            wealth[years + 1] = (wealth[years]*(1+r+noise)) - y_r
    
    temp.append(wealth)

print (mean(wealth_retirement))
```

Comment: Please post a more representative sample of your code, along with the specific error you are encountering. All we can say now is that your one of your indices is greater than the length of one of your lists.

Comment: What are the lengths of your lists?

Comment: Hi, I uploaded a little more detail and an Image of the formula i'm trying to recreate within the nested for loop. Is there a way I can recreate this formula without having to deal with the list out of index error?

Answer (score 1):

If your code is written literally, meaning

```
wealth_retirement = list() 
wealth = list()   
temp = list()
```

is how they are defined in your actual use, not just for posting here - that is the source of your problem. You are trying to access elements in an empty list. Python does not allow you to add elements to lists by referencing an index that does not exist.

You can either make a list of zeros with the required length prior to your for loops and reset them as you go, or use `.append()` to add new elements.

It is also hard to tell what the error is because you have not provided the structure of the variables that are coming from your GUI.

Here you use `noise` as a list:

```
wealth[years + 1] = (wealth[years]*(1+r+noise[years])) + w_y
```

but here you use it as a single value:

```
wealth[years + 1] = (wealth[years]*(1+r+noise)) - y_r
```

Answer (score -1):

It is because „temp”, „wealth” and „wealth_retirement” are not lists.

Comment: Welcome, we're having trouble understanding this solution. Would you be able to provide the correct data type and explain why in your post?